# Delete spaces before text only

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I delete spaces before only text:

```
"          with spaces between"
```

I need:

```
"some text with spaces between"
```

All I have found it's `text.replace(/\s/g, '')` but it doesn't work well:

```
"sometextwithspacesbetween"
```

and `indexOf(' ') + 25` also isn't good solve, because I have a different text and number of spaces before it.

If it possible, help me please

Comment: [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032024/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-white-spaces-from-a-given-html-string

Possible Duplicate?

Comment: Question shows no effort to research. Not hard to find lots of answers for this

Comment: And what do you expect about any extra spaces after text? Should it be removed or kept?

Answer (score 1):

Set the reg exp to look for the beginning of the string

```
text.replace(/^\s+/, '')
```

Comment: Whoops, missed that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)** in javascript and **[`jQuery.trim(string)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** in jQuery. Both of them remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

```js
var str = "                         some text with spaces between";
console.log(str);

console.log(str.trim());
console.log(jQuery.trim(str));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```