# RegEx to Remove Trailing Space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following RegEx:

```
$('.my-selector').each(function(){
  var t = $(this).text(),
      id = t.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  id  = id.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, "");
});
```

This repalces all spaces with a `-` and then removes any character that isn't `a-z`, `0-9` or `-`. This works but I noticed one thing, if I have a trailing space it becomes a `-`. For examples. `My (test) string` becomes `my-test-string-`

How to I remove the last `-` (or ) from the very end of the string?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032024/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-white-spaces-from-a-given-html-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be to chain the [`.trim()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) before replacing the whitespace. In doing so, the trailing whitespace is removed.

```
string.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-')
```

It would output `my-test-string`:

```
var text = 'My (test) string ';
var id = text.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-')
             .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '');

console.log(id); // my-test-string
```

---

Of course, you could alternatively just use a negative lookahead in order to prevent the whitespace at the end from being replaced:

```
string.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+(?!\s*$)/g, '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$('.my-selector').each(function(){
  var t = $(this).text(),
      id = t.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  id  = id.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, "").replace(/-$/, '');
});
```